# if elseif else com operador condicional ? e : em PHP

Tags: php

Sabemos que existe uma maneira de fazer um if else utilizando operador condicional, porem gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer um IF ELSE IF ELSE no PHP utilizando operador condicional? se sim como? poderiam me mandar um exemplo?

Comment: `a()? b()? C: D : E`; onde se obtém `C` sss `a() &&b()`, `D` sss `a() && !b()` e `E` sss `!a()`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nao entendi

Comment: @Rui , terminei agora, tinha pressionado enviar antes do tempo sem querer

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o que seria sss  ?

Comment: "Se e somente se"

Comment: $a ? $b : ( $c ? $d : ( $e ? $f : $g ) ) Apenas um aviso, instruções ternárias aninhadas são difíceis de ler.